# Handling messages to the first responder in a view controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, first-responder, nsviewcontroller

I must be missing something simple, but I can't see it.  First, the setup:

- `DATreeView`, a subclass of `NSView`
- `DATreeViewController`, a subclass of `NSViewController`
- `MainMenu.xib` has an instance of `DATreeViewController`, which is configured to load a view from `DATreeView.xib`
- `MainMenu.xib` also has an instance of `DendreaAppDelegate`, which has a `DATreeViewController` outlet (which is wired up to `MainMenu.xib`'s `DATreeViewController` instance.
- `Do Something!`, a menu item wired up to send a `doSomething:` message to the First Responder.
- Not coincidentally, `DATreeViewController` has an action called `doSomething:`.

What I want is for the `Do Something!` menu item to trigger the `doSomething:` action on `DATreeViewController`, and let's pretend I can't just set the target/action connection directly.  I'll stop right here and ask, is my design totally wrong?  Is what I'm trying to do stupid/evil/likely to shame me in the eyes of my God?

No?  Great.  Now, for the life of me, I can't get the menu item to be active.  I'm doing this on Snow Leopard, if that makes any difference.

In order to achieve good integration between `NSView` and `NSViewController`, e.g. managing the responder chain, I've followed [Matt Gallagher's example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/better-integration-for-nsviewcontroller.html), with one substantive change: at no point in the NIB loading process does `NSView` seem to receive a `setViewController:` message, so I send that message myself in `DATreeViewController`'s `loadView` message.  From what I can tell, after running the following code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
NSView *view = self.treeViewController.view;
[self.window.contentView addSubview:view];
```

the responder chain is set up as expected, that is:

```
NSWindow < NSView < DATreeViewController < DATreeView
```

It was my expectation that, being as `DATreeViewController` is part of the responder chain, and being as it responds to `doSomething:`, and being as it implements no validation, all I would have to do is use Interface Builder to wire the `Do Something!` menu item to the First Responder proxy, with `doSomething:` as its action, and the menu item would be active automatically.

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you all for your invaluable assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your view accept and successfully become first responder?

Comment: Ah!  Since the action was in the view controller, that's where I was overriding -acceptsFirstResponder.  But the view controller isn't in the view hierarchy!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is DATreeViewController wired to the DATreeView's viewController outlet in IB?

Have you traced through setViewController: and setNextResponder: to verify that nextResponder is being set up properly?

Comment: Turns out it was simpler than that.  Since the action is in the view controller, that's where I was overriding -acceptsFirstResponder.  But Cocoa only looks at the view hierarchy for a responder, and DAView wasn't accepting first responder...

Answer (score 0):

The responder chain only works for messages in the `NSResponder` superclass such as `mouseDown` `mouseExited` etc. I believe you can do something sneaky by adding a category to `NSResponder` to bubble up other methods by looking at the `nextResponder` and sending the message up if `nextResponder` exists.

This appears to be an example of this technique: https://github.com/MrNoodle/NoodleKit/blob/master/NSResponder-NoodleModalExtensions.m